# How do I query a non-Wordpress table?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a new table within the same database that contains the Wordpress tables. How can I query this specific table from a custom php page? The page can't seem to connect to the db. It's been a while since I have had to do any php/mysql coding, so forgive my ignorance.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$result = mysqli_query($wpdb, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "id: " . $row["ID"]. " " . $row["content"]. "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$wpdb` is an instance of the [wpdb class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). You make calls to it like the following:

```
global $wpdb;

//Prepare a SQL Query
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_custom_table WHERE column_foo = %s", $someVariable);

$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

foreach($results as $result) {
    //do a thing
}
```